# Linearization of Conditional Constraints for MIP using Cplex

Tags: cplex, linearization, scheduling, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

I'm currently working on a mixed-integer programming (MIP) problem and I'm trying to implement a set of conditional constraints in CPlex. These constraints involve decision variables that are indexed by the value of other variables. Specifically, I have the following types of constraints:

\begin{align}
x_{ct} = X_{ci} \ \ \ \ \ \forall c \in Crane, \ \ i \in Job, t \in [S_{ci}, ..., S_{ci}+p_{ci}[
\end{align}

This constraint holds when Crane $c$ starts job $i$ during time $S_{ci},...,S_{ci}+p_{ci}$. I understand that this constraint involves conditional indexing and need to be linearized for Cplex. Could you please provide guidance on how I can linearize these constraints in CPlex?

Additionally, if you're looking for relevant literature on this topic, I found the paper by Dorndorf and Schneider (2010) titled "Scheduling automated triple cross-over stacking cranes in a container yard" to be insightful.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. I am unsure to understand what you are looking for, but if you mean by `when Crane c
 starts job i
 during time ...`, you will need to define a binary variable $z_{c,i,t}$ and an implication constraint as if ($z_{c,i,t} = 1) \implies (x_{c,t} = X_{c,i})$. Then it can be written in the OPL as: (z[c,i,t]==1) => (x[c,t]==X[c,i]); Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry if my question was a bit complicated and difficult to understand.

I might provide some additional explanation about the variable $S_{ci}$. 
$S_{ci}$ is start time of job $i$ performed by crane $c$. And $p_{ci}$ is a parameter that is process time of job $i$. So those constraints involve decision variables in an index $t$, so when condition $t = S_{ci}~S_{ci}+p_{ci}$, those constraints holds.

I had asked because I want to implement constraints from the paper in Cplex. It seems like using $z_{cit}$ could be a good approach. I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. If the decision variable is in the index [this](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360071776111-use-a-decision-variable-as-an-index-) and [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9970/modelling-a-decision-variable-as-an-index-of-a-fixed-set) links also might be helpful.